# USB hub operates with input devices, but not with network adapters

Tags: usb-hub

The USB hub operates with a mouse or keyboard or a bluetooth adapter; but not with a WiFi adapter or USB wimax adapter(connected individually). The WiFi adapter is not recognized, instead lights up dimly, as it would when windows just starts to boot(when windows completely boots up and my PC hotspot is broadcasting, the adapter lights up brightly). The USB wimax adapter red LED would fluctuate and windows would inform that this device would perform faster if connected to some enlisted USB 2.0 port. Neither of the two could be put to work.

Why? I got the impression that these adapters requires more power than the PC could possibly provide through the hub. Is there a workaround, such that using an AC/DC adapter to power the hub externally, or something like that?

[The USB hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzI26.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Because your hub is host powered at the moment it is likely reporting <100mA per port in order to be able to use all the ports at the same time.  The WiFi devices negotiate with the hub, get told they do not have enough power and so fall back to their standby mode.

USB keyboards and mice require only a small amount of power to work, much less than a WiFi device and so are fine with the restricted power situation.

You either need to find a power adaptor for that hub, or you need to find a powered hub.

---

Your PC will only output 500mA per port, devices plugged in can state they need less and negotiate with the host but the cannot draw more. If you plug in an unpowered hub, then that hub must split and share that initial 500mA across ports. It can do this by telling plugged in devices about the low power situation and let them act accordingly.

When you apply external power to the hub then that hub can supply the full 500mA *per port*, and report to the plugged in devices accordingly. The devices would then start up as if they were plugged in to the PC as they have a full allocation of power available.

---

Just because your hub *can* supply more power to each device, as you only have a single device plugged in, does not mean it will.

Per the [Wikipedia USB hub page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub#Power):

> A USB's electric current is allocated in units of 100 mA up to a maximum total of 500 mA per port. Therefore, a compliant bus powered hub can have no more than four downstream ports and cannot offer more than four 100 mA units of current in total to downstream devices (since the hub needs one unit for itself). If a device requires more units of current than the port it is plugged into can supply, the operating system usually reports this to the user.
>
> In contrast, a self-powered hub is one that takes its power from an external power supply unit and can therefore provide full power (up to 500 mA) to every port. Many hubs can operate as either bus powered or self powered hubs.

So the maximum you hub can supply is 4 x 100mA but, not knowing if you are going to be plugging more devices in, it is highly unlikely that it will report the full 400mA as being available to any one port. Instead it is more likely that it "plays fair" with the power and reports that each port can have 100mA.

I might expect and expensive unpowered hub to have the smarts to be able to dynamically allocated power units on a per-port basis, but dumb cheap devices are likely to be poorly made and either not smart enough or not really compliant with the standard.

Comment: Thanks, but I assume the 500 mA the PC supplies would _not_ split up in the case when I use a singular device with the hub? I actually tried each adapters separately with the hub. Also, how would I externally power the hub, when I have to? With an AC/DC adapter, I presume? But you can see from the image I have added that the hub has 4 output ports, and a fifth USB cable that has to connect to the PC. It would not work if I connected one of the 4 ports to the PC instead and spared this fifth USB cable to connect to an AC/DC adapter. Is my hub not even compatible to external powering?

Comment: Your hub needs a dedicated DC power inlet, you can't just plug an AC to USB adaptor. If your hub doesn't have a DC power input then you need a new hub that does. Usually the power in is via a round "barrel" connector. Just because you don't want power to be split doesn't mean that the hub isn't telling your devices that it doesn't have a full port (500mA) worth of power available for them, that is up to the maker of the USB chip to decide and enforce.

Comment: @TonyMarshle I have updated my answer.